# 共同で使用するWiFiの内部に別のルーターを介しセグメントを分ける方法

Tags: network

`Synergy`というLAN内にある複数のPCやMacでキーボードとマウスが共有できるソフトを使おうとしたのですが、ネットワークの問題か動作しませんでした。
そしてルーターの設定にアクセスする権限がありません。

問題の特定をしやすくするために別のルーターか中継機を購入しセグメントを区切りたいのですがどのような仕様を満たせば可能なのかわかりませんでした。

そもそもそのようなことは可能なのでしょうか？
またどのような機能のものを購入するべきか教えて下さい。

今はインターネットに繋がっているメインのルーターのSSIDとパスを個別のPCが入力しています。
もちろんセグメントを切り分けた後もネットの接続は必要になります。

#### 追記

Synergyの接続はIPアドレスを用いて一旦ファイアウォールを無効にした状態で試しました。

Comment: プライバシーセパレーター機能でWi-Fi接続端末同士の通信を不可にしているように思われます。この機能はルーターではなく無線APに備わった機能です。Wi-Fiでアクセスする無線APはルーターとは別なのでしょうか？それともルーターにWi-Fiを受け付ける無線AP機能があるのでしょうか？別の場合、無線APの設定は変更できるのでしょうか？

Comment: タイトルから勝手に想像してしまいましたが、全てのPCは有線ではなく無線(Wi-Fi)で接続していると言うことでいいのですよね？

Comment: http://babyp.blog55.fc2.com/blog-entry-153.html 等でトラブルシューティングを書いている人がいましたが・・、マシン名として登録した場合に マシン名から IP アドレスを取得する事ができないパターンがある。 固定IPを割り当てればいいのですが、 ルーターに アクセスする権限を持たないのであれば、無線LAN 接続で 固定IP を割り当てる事は ほぼ 不可能。 なので・・安定運用のためには、 ルーターの設定変更をして 固定IP 設定がいいと思います。 ※ Windows Firewall の最低限の設定変更は 理解して設定している前提・・。

Comment: 「プライバシーセパレーター機能でWi-Fi接続端末同士の通信を不可」にしているかどうかは、無線LAN 接続で接続した端末同士で 相手の IP アドレスを PING するとか どちらかに 共有フォルダの設定をして そのフォルダを 無線LAN 接続の時に閲覧可能か？ を確認すれば 確認できます。 有線 LAN では 可能なのに、無線の時に できないのであれば、 Wi-Fi 接続で 無線LANのアクセスポイント（Wi-Fi ルーター) が 端末間の 通信を遮断している可能性が高いです。

Comment: @らっしー はい、全てWi-Fiの接続です。ルーター・無線APの状態は把握できずネットを使うためにSSIDとパスが共有されてるだけになっています。

Comment: @ksystem 設定はIPアドレスで行い、FirewallもWindows側、Mac側両方オフにして試してダメだったのでやはりルーター側の問題のようですね。ルーターの設定ができるか頼んでみたり、他の方法がないか模索することにします。

Comment: そもそも他人に管理されているネットワークに問題があるからといって、独自の無線APを立てるのは認められているのでしょうか？ 同様の人が乱立させたらまともに通信できなくなるので、普通は禁止されているように思うのですが…。

Comment: @sayuri 乱立はされていませんし、チャンネルを分ければ問題ないと思っていたのですが設置するときは一応管理者に確認することにします。

Comment: Synergy につなぎたい２台の パソコンに LAN ケーブルで HUB をつないで、無線LAN で 割り当てられるIP アドレスと異なるセグメントの IP アドレスを手動設定すると、簡単に コンピュータ間の 通信の動作確認はできると思います。 デフォルトゲートウェイを 無線LAN で自動設定される値を参照して 設定すれば、インターネット接続の場合は デフォルトゲートウェイ経由で 外部に出ていくので、インターネットにもつながります。

Comment: 両方にBluetoothがついているなら、モバイルホットスポット(Windows 10)やインターネット共有(Mac)が使えるかも知れません。(Wi-Fiは既にインターネット接続に使われているため、Wi-Fiでもできるかどうかは不明です)

Comment: もう一つ。野良無線APは2.4GHz帯の使用可能チャンネル数を圧迫し、重なり合ったチャンネル同士の干渉によって通信障害が起きる可能性があるため、原則禁止にしている組織はあります。とくに、大学は軒並みどこも(建前上は)禁止していると聞きます。